# Volley library throws application exception

Tags: android-volley

I am adding my two separate android activities in one application, one of my activity having volley library but it gives me an exception that appcontroller(volley library) its an application not an activity please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Ya, you have mention in your manifest file appcontroller class as Application. This solves the exception.

Comment: i do mentioned it as  <application 
        android:name="uzair.sabir.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" /> exception has been removed but when i use to press button it does not perform my activity

Comment: @uzair you edit your question with full code, manifest file and stacktrace, instead of posting as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Main Acitivity:

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener {

```
MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabHost mTabHost;
private Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    // Tab Initialization
    initialiseTabHost();

    // Fragments and ViewPager Initialization
    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
}

// Method to add a TabHost
private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec,String message,int picture,Context x) 
{
    tabSpec.setContent(new MyTabFactory(activity));
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(x).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(message);

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setBackgroundDrawable(x.getResources().getDrawable(picture));
    icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    tabSpec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

// Manages the Tab changes, synchronizing it with Pages
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

    for(int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        //mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.Color.transperant);
    }
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);// selected
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view){
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((ImageView) view);
}
// Manages the Page changes, synchronizing it with Tabs
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    int pos = this.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(pos);
}

@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    // TODO Put here your Fragments
    NewSampleFragment f1 = NewSampleFragment.newInstance(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.newfragment_a);
    MySampleFragment f2 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("Sample Fragment 2");
    MySampleFragment f3 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("Sample Fragment 3");
    MySampleFragment f4 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("Sample Fragment 4");
    MySampleFragment f5 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("Sample Fragment 5");
    fList.add(f1);
    fList.add(f2);
    fList.add(f3);
    fList.add(f4);
    fList.add(f5);
    return fList;
}

// Tabs Creation
private void initialiseTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    // TODO Put here your Tabs
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),"Grocery",R.drawable.movies,getApplicationContext());
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),"Crockery",R.drawable.artist,getApplicationContext());
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"),"Foods",R.drawable.song,getApplicationContext());
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab4"),"Drinks",R.drawable.shopping,getApplicationContext());
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab5"),"Toys",R.drawable.play,getApplicationContext());

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

OfferActivity (This should be open when button pressed)

public class OfferActivity extends Activity 
{

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String URL_FEED = "http://nusdtech.com/public_html/checking2.php";
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // These two lines not needed,
    // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
    //getActionBar().setIcon(
        //     new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_FEED,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            FeedItem movie = new FeedItem();


                            movie.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
                            movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));

                            // Image might be null sometimes
                            String image = obj.isNull("image") ? null : obj
                                    .getString("image");
                            movie.setImge(image);
                            movie.setStatus(obj.getString("status"));
                            movie.setProfilePic(obj.getString("profilePic"));
                            //movie.setTimeStamp(obj.getString("price"));
                            movie.setPrice(obj.getString("price"));
                            movie.setDate(obj.getString("dates"));

                                feedItems.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}
private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

AppController:

public class AppController extends Application {

```
public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
LruBitmapCache mLruBitmapCache;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        getLruBitmapCache();
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache);
    }

    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public LruBitmapCache getLruBitmapCache() {
    if (mLruBitmapCache == null)
        mLruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
    return this.mLruBitmapCache;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Activity that contain fragment buttons

public class NewSampleFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static View mView;
private Context con;
public static final NewSampleFragment newInstance(Context con,int layout) {
    NewSampleFragment f = new NewSampleFragment();
    con=con;
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("mylayout",layout);
    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int layout = getArguments().getInt("mylayout");
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfragment_a, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.bactivity);
    Button offer=(Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.aactivity);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ListViewDemo.class);
            //Optional parameters
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
            Log.e("Error","Kashif");
        } 
    });  
    offer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startApplication("uzair.sabir.app.OfferActivity");

        } 
    });  
    return mView;
}
public void startApplication(String application_name){
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveinfo_list = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for(ResolveInfo info:resolveinfo_list){
            if(info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(application_name)){
                launchComponent("uzair.sabir.app", "OfferActivity");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was a problem loading the application: "+application_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());    
    }
}
private void  launchComponent(String packageName, String name){
    Intent launch_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    launch_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    launch_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
    launch_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getActivity().startActivity(launch_intent);
}
```

}